# How do I get a zooming effect on an image when a user hovers over it?

Tags: jquery, css, web, css-transitions

Here is an very visually pleasing effect that I found on the [Nikon](http://ashton.nikonusa.com/Digital-SLR/Cameras/D3200exp.aspx) site. The images tend to zoom in when I hover over them.

Is it possible to achieve this using CSS? If so how?

Comment: http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/hover-zoom-effect-with-jquery-and-css/

Comment: With all due respect, please do leave comments reasoning out the down votes so I may learn as to what not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good example of CSS hovers. Refer to the zoom & pan section: "Zoom and Pan"

Check [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/) and [this](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/imagehovers/zoomandpan.html) link

```
/*GROW*/
.grow img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/) might be  something like what your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This link will help you
http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom

Zoom appends html inside the element it is assigned to, so that element has to be able to accept html,
 like `<a>`, `<span>`, `<li>`, `<div>`, etc. This excludes `<img>` elements (see below).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
    });

    // Using ColorBox with Zoom
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.photo').zoom({
            url: 'photo-big.jpg', 
            callback: function(){
                $(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
            }
        });

});
```

To use zoom with img elements, they will need to be wrapped with another element. It is impossible to read some layout related CSS styles from JavaScript (percent-based width and height, margins set to auto, etc.) so the safe thing to do is to defer this change to individual site owners. The following is all that is needed in some cases:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img')
        .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
        .css('display', 'block')
        .parent()
        .zoom();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can! It's quite simple with css3's `transform: scale()` property in conjunction with css3 transitions.

```
.thumbnail:hover img {
     transform: scale(1.15);
    -o-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szqzF/)**